# Mirrored Left-Click Select

Tags: interface, select, mouse, keymap

So I'm going to change my life tonight by flipping my right and left mouse buttons for my system.

Only problem is my Blender set up is currently Right-Click Select as is just and true.

When I flip the mouse buttons, that will also flip. The "select with" toggle is only available if I switch my keymap preferences back to "Blender" which will overwrite my other shortcuts.

I want to keep my current custom keys and only switch the left and right click. Hopefully not manually:

[image]

I want Left-Click-Select to perform *exactly* as Right-Click-Select but mirrored (i.e. without the context menu) so that when I flip the hardware buttons everything essentially goes back to normal. That is, my whole system will flip except Blender:

[image]

I'm currently running 3.4.1

I can't seem to find a program that will let me flip mouse buttons per application focus. My system prefs and my mouse both have the option but it is a global change vs a more granular one.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for reading.